# Перемножение в таблице с одинаковыми классами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется таблица[image]

Нужно посчитать сумму и не догоняю как реализовать единый метод без костылей для каждой строки таблицы, с учетом того, что классы одинаковы. Структура таблицы:

```
    <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Тип</th>
                <th>Количество</th>
                <th>Цена</th>
                <th>Сумма</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 70%;">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">Event Expo (включает 2 билета Partner, промо-активности и место в экспо-зоне 1х1м)</div>
                    <div>
                        В билет включены: - 2 welcome-pack участника - 2 бейджа с полным доступом на все сессии - бесплатные напитки (чай, кофе, вода) - разрешение на проведение промо-активностей в фойе - площадь 1х1 кв.м с розеткой для установки стенда - стойка и плазменная панель при необходимости - 2 браслета на вечерние программы
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select name="tickets" id="tickets__select">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td id="tickets__price" value="95000">95 000 руб.</td>
                <td id="tickets__total" value="0">0 руб.</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">Event Expo (включает 2 билета Partner, промо-активности и место в экспо-зоне 1х1м)</div>
                    <div>
                        В билет включены: - 2 welcome-pack участника - 2 бейджа с полным доступом на все сессии - бесплатные напитки (чай, кофе, вода) - разрешение на проведение промо-активностей в фойе - площадь 1х1 кв.м с розеткой для установки стенда - стойка и плазменная панель при необходимости - 2 браслета на вечерние программы
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select name="tickets" id="tickets__select">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td id="tickets__price" value="95000">95 000 руб.</td>
                <td id="tickets__total" value="0">0 руб.</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">Event Expo (включает 2 билета Partner, промо-активности и место в экспо-зоне 1х1м)</div>
                    <div>
                        В билет включены: - 2 welcome-pack участника - 2 бейджа с полным доступом на все сессии - бесплатные напитки (чай, кофе, вода) - разрешение на проведение промо-активностей в фойе - площадь 1х1 кв.м с розеткой для установки стенда - стойка и плазменная панель при необходимости - 2 браслета на вечерние программы
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select name="tickets" id="tickets__select">
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td id="tickets__price" value="95000">95 000 руб.</td>
                <td id="tickets__total" value="0">0 руб.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
  </tr>  
  </tfoot>  
</table>
```

Метод:

```
<script>
    let price = document.getElementById('tickets__price').getAttribute('value');
    let select = document.getElementById('tickets__select');
    let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        document.getElementById('tickets__total').innerHTML = (price * value).toLocaleString('ru') + ' руб.';
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что поменял:

• id (англ. identifier) - может быть только у одного элемента. В этом и смысл, чтобы его найти по конкретному id. Поменял везде ваши id на `class`. И записал по сути то же самое, что у вас - только прогнал через цикл и повесил события `change` на все селекты с этим классом.

• `value="..."` у элементов td возвращает `undefined`, если записывать `.value`. Поэтому, показалось удобнее добавить `data-value="..."` тогда написанное число оттуда можно достать через `...dataset.value` (вместо value могло бы быть любое другое слово)

• Т.к. `value` всех опций совпадает с их внутренним текстом, можно не пытаться достать именно value, а взять просто внутренний текст, через `select.value` - всё равно число то же самое (и в таком случае вообще можно убрать значения опций)

```js
(function(){

let select = document.getElementsByClassName('tickets__select');
let price =  document.getElementsByClassName('tickets__price');
let total =  document.getElementsByClassName('tickets__total');

for(let i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
  select[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    let a = this.value; 
    let b = price[i].dataset.value;
    total[i].innerText = (a*b).toLocaleString('ru') + ' руб.'
  });
}

})();
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Тип</th>
      <th>Количество</th>
      <th>Цена</th>
      <th>Сумма</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 70%;">
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Event Expo (включает 2 билета Partner, промо-активности и место в экспо-зоне 1х1м)</div>
        <div>
          В билет включены: - 2 welcome-pack участника - 2 бейджа с полным доступом на все сессии - бесплатные напитки (чай, кофе, вода) - разрешение на проведение промо-активностей в фойе - площадь 1х1 кв.м с розеткой для установки стенда - стойка и плазменная панель при необходимости - 2 браслета на вечерние программы
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="tickets" class="tickets__select">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td class="tickets__price" data-value="95000">95 000 руб.</td>
      <td class="tickets__total" data-value="0">0 руб.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Event Expo (включает 2 билета Partner, промо-активности и место в экспо-зоне 1х1м)</div>
        <div>
          В билет включены: - 2 welcome-pack участника - 2 бейджа с полным доступом на все сессии - бесплатные напитки (чай, кофе, вода) - разрешение на проведение промо-активностей в фойе - площадь 1х1 кв.м с розеткой для установки стенда - стойка и плазменная панель при необходимости - 2 браслета на вечерние программы
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="tickets" class="tickets__select">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td class="tickets__price" data-value="95000">95 000 руб.</td>
      <td class="tickets__total" data-value="0">0 руб.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Event Expo (включает 2 билета Partner, промо-активности и место в экспо-зоне 1х1м)</div>
        <div>
          В билет включены: - 2 welcome-pack участника - 2 бейджа с полным доступом на все сессии - бесплатные напитки (чай, кофе, вода) - разрешение на проведение промо-активностей в фойе - площадь 1х1 кв.м с розеткой для установки стенда - стойка и плазменная панель при необходимости - 2 браслета на вечерние программы
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select name="tickets" class="tickets__select">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td class="tickets__price" data-value="95000">95 000 руб.</td>
      <td class="tickets__total" data-value="0">0 руб.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
</table>
```

P.s.

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test').innerText;

test = test.replace(/\s+/g, ""); // Заменили пробелы (\space) на ничто

console.log( test );

// Достает число из строки, пока может. Наткнется на что-то другое, кроме цифры - остановится.
console.log( parseFloat( test ) ); 

console.log( parseFloat( test ).toLocaleString('ru') );
```

```html
<div id="test">95 000 000 рублей</div>
```

Это к тому, что можно было вообще без value обойтись)